# Multiple datepickers on one page each with dynamic ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a form cloning plugin ([SheepIt](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&)) which clones form elements and, in my case, each form contains a jQuery datepicker.

In "normal" forms I have attached the datepicker to the class and it works even when I have multiple datepickers on one page but as I cannot know how many items there may be on the form so don't know how to add it to the ID.

When I try this with SheepIt cloning I get the error:

```
Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker
```

Example (where I have simulated three text boxes but there could be one or there could be twenty):

```
<form>
    <div id="sheepItForm">
        <label for "start_date">Start date:</label>
        <input id="sheepItForm_0_start_date" type="text" name="start_date_0" class="datepicker">
        <label for "start_date">Start date:</label>
        <input id="sheepItForm_1_start_date" type="text" name="start_date_1" class="datepicker">
        <label for "start_date">Start date:</label>
        <input id="sheepItForm_2_start_date" type="text" name="start_date_2" class="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });    
});
```

SheepIt code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        var sheepItForm = $('#sheepItForm').sheepIt({
            separator: '',
            allowRemoveLast: true,
            allowRemoveCurrent: true,
            allowRemoveAll: true,
            allowAdd: true,
            allowAddN: true,
            maxFormsCount: 50,
            minFormsCount: 0,
            iniFormsCount: 1,
            removeLastConfirmation: true,
            removeCurrentConfirmation: true,
            removeAllConfirmation: true,
            removeLastConfirmationMsg: 'Are you sure? This will remove the last added item',
            removeCurrentConfirmationMsg: 'Are you sure? This will remove this item',
            removeAllConfirmationMsg: 'Are you sure? This will remove all items'
        });  
    });
</script>
```

How can I get the datepicker to work on any datepicker box when the quantity (and therefore the ID) are unknown?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/57MZf/4/) is working already. You just need to include jquery-ui library (on the left menu in jsfiddle).

Comment: I would suggest going without `id`'s if possible!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work "live" when the SheepIt code clones the form elements - I was trying to avoid having to setup SheepIt for JSFiddle to make it easier but I failed!

Comment: Why do you even need ID's? You can access things with `this` and traverse accordingly

Comment: The SheepIt script uses ID's so I am assuming it needs them - I don't normally use ID's for normal form items with datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SheepIt has a callback once the cloned form is added (`afterAdd`). You can initialise datepicker there:

```
    var sheepItForm = $('#sheepItForm').sheepIt({
        separator: '',
        allowRemoveLast: true,
        allowRemoveCurrent: true,
        allowRemoveAll: true,
        allowAdd: true,
        allowAddN: true,
        maxFormsCount: 50,
        minFormsCount: 0,
        iniFormsCount: 1,
        removeLastConfirmation: true,
        removeCurrentConfirmation: true,
        removeAllConfirmation: true,
        removeLastConfirmationMsg: 'Are you sure? This will remove the last added item',
        removeCurrentConfirmationMsg: 'Are you sure? This will remove this item',
        removeAllConfirmationMsg: 'Are you sure? This will remove all items',

        // Callback - initialise datepicker
        afterAdd: function(source, newForm) {
             $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                 firstDay: 1,
                 dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
             });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to use beforeAdd and afterAdd with the initialisation code in both but it works now